ssd1306 lcd (64x32) only half screen working
I have ssd1306 lcd with 64x32 resolutinon connected to I2C on STM32F103.
I try to place some text and line on screen but see only half of data.
I think something in my init code...
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xAE); //display off

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x20); //Set Memory Addressing Mode
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x00); //00,Horizontal Addressing Mode;01,Vertical Addressing Mode;10,Page Addressing Mode (RESET);11,Invalid

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xB0); //Set Page Start Address for Page Addressing Mode,0-7

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xC0); //mirror vert
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x40); //--set start line address

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x81); //--set contrast control register
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xFF);

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xA0); //--set segment re-map 0 to 127

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xA6); //--set normal display

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xA8); //--set multiplex ratio(1 to 64)
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x1F); //32 active line on display

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xA4); //0xa4,Output follows RAM content;0xa5,Output ignores RAM content

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xD3); //-set display offset
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x00); //-not offset

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xD5); //--set display clock divide ratio/oscillator frequency
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xF0); //--set divide ratio

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xD9); //--set pre-charge period
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x22); //

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xDA); //--set com pins hardware configuration
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x12);

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xDB); //--set vcomh
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x20); //0x20,0.77xVcc

    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x8D); //--set DC-DC enable
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x14); //
    SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xAF); //--turn on SSD1306 panel

        /* Clear screen */
    SSD1306_Fill(SSD1306_COLOR_BLACK);
    
    /* Update screen */
    SSD1306_UpdateScreen();
    
    /* Set default values */
    SSD1306.CurrentX = 0;
    SSD1306.CurrentY = 0;

main code
char* strin3 = "01234567";
SSD1306_Init();
SSD1306_GotoXY(0,0);
SSD1306_Puts(strin3, &Font_7x10, 1);
SSD1306_UpdateScreen();

SSD1306_DrawLine(1,1,63,31,1);
SSD1306_UpdateScreen();


And what I see

I try some changes in the code and I can change the shift in the vertical direction, mirror in the vertical direction.
And if I send 0xA5 (All indicator ON - Output ignores RAM parameter), then I see a full screen filled
0xA5
ANSWER
I got it. As i understand, this small displays active memory region for horizontal line is in the middle of memory region of 128x64. So i place all data in cols 32 to 96, and all seems good now.
good

This is just a wild guess, but try configuring the display as 32x64 instead, and draw things in both the top and bottom half of that area.  There are 16x1 character text LCDs that are actually organized as 8x2, simply because they're cheaper to build that way, and I'm wondering if some similar cost optimization might apply to the ssd1306.

Your init is longer than it necessary. When SSD1306 is power-up, there is a default value for each setting, you only need to configure those that you want to change the default value. BTW, SetCOMOutputScanDirection(C0h/C8h) is a single byte command, not as you did with SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0xC0);  follow by SSD1306_WRITECOMMAND(0x40);.
